# Fade in datatable each time you use select / input filters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fadein

Pretty straightforward question: how do I make it so that the datatable fades in each time the user selects an option or inputs as part of a filter?

I want it to have a nice fade in effect each time the user searches. It currently automatically searches the datatable, using `.draw()`.

[image]

Here's the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="select">
    <select id="officeSelector" class="form-select" data-width="100%" data-size="8" name="country" data-dropdown>
        <option value="">Office (All)</option>
        <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
        <option value="San Fransisco">San Franscisco</option>
        <option value="Edinburgh">Edinburgh</option>
    </select>
</div>

<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Minimum age:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="min" name="min"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Maximum age:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="max" name="max"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011-04-25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011-07-25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009-01-12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012-03-29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008-11-28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var min = parseInt($('#min').val(), 10);
    var max = parseInt($('#max').val(), 10);
    var age = parseFloat(data[3]) || 0; //

    if (
        (isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
        (isNaN(min) && age <= max) ||
        (min <= age && isNaN(max)) ||
        (min <= age && age <= max)
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "simple",
        "ordering": "false",
        "select": "single",
        "dom": '<<t>ip>'
    });
    $('#min, #max').keyup(function () {
        oTable.draw();
    });
    $('select#officeSelector').change(function () {
        oTable.columns(2).search($(this).val()).draw();
    });
});
```

**Libraries**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```